# UINavigation controller back title is ignores previous title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I would like my navigation controller to act the way that ios7 does = display the previous view title.

It doesn't always work for me

I have a `SettingViewController` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"account_settings", nil,[GeneralUtil getLangBundle],nil);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When clicking on a button it opens the Profile Picture view controller like this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard profilePictureStoryBoard]instantiateInitialViewController];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The profile picture is opened successfully but the title of the back button is `Back` and not the title of the Settings View controller which is Settings.
What could be the problem?

Comment: may be you have set back title  of in Profile Picture view controller storyboard remove it .

Comment: where could it be in storyboard?

Comment: select profile controller in that select the navigation controller go in inspector 4th one check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back button changes its text in iOS 7 depending on the length of the title it needs to display.

If the name of the previous viewcontroller is too long to fit, it will instead just say 'Back'. If there's not even enough room for 'Back', it will just show the arrow.

Comment: How can I localized it? added 3 values for back in my English and Spanish localization files and I set the language via AppleLanguages Bundle. However the Back is not being changed unless I restart the app. Any idea what to do in this case?

Comment: When a user changes their device's language in the Settings app, the device will restart springboard and your app will be relaunched - so the new language should take effect the next time the user runs it.

Comment: I mean changing via settings AppleLanguages bundle