# Localized UITabBarItem "Back" title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, localization, uinavigationcontroller

When the text of the previous UIViewController in UINavigationController is too long, the UITabBarItem displays ["Back"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329859/uinavigation-controller-back-title-is-ignores-previous-title/21330171?noredirect=1#21330171)

In my app, I allow the user to change the language by the following code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:locale forKey:@"locale"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:locale, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

*locale would be "en" or "es" etc.*

I also add to my localizable files the back text. I see that when the user opens the app, it would display "back" according to the text in the localizable files. But if the user changes the language with the above code, he would need to restart the app for the changes in AppleLanguages bundle to work.

I need also for the text on the UIPickerController *e.g. Remove*

How could it be fixed so the user wouldn't need to restart the app after setting the locale?

Comment: see this post, it could be a valid solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351445/runtime-change-the-language-localization-in-three20

Comment: Not sure - it's for FB specific implementation. I didn't understand who calls the get method from AppDelegate for the Back button

Comment: Why don't you instead respect the device language, rather than trying to set it in app?

Comment: These are the requirements that I got. To enable the user to choose a different language for the app

Answer (score 2):

@Dejel: use "TSLanguageManager" library it's change the localze text at the runtime you don't need to restart the app after setting the locale.

you can download example from below link:

https://github.com/tonisalae/TSLanguageManager

Comment: Sorry, I checked it again but it doesn't change the UIPickerController values e.g. cancel

Comment: Hi, I need to restart the app in order for changes in elements like UIImagePicker also take the new language changes. I was looking for something that the user wouldn't need to restart the app for Apple component (regular text works just fine)

Answer (score 1):

@Dejel: use "LanguagesManager" library it's change the localze text at the runtime you don't need to restart the app after setting the locale.

you can download example from below link:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/languagesmanager

Comment: will it help me for changing UIPickerController values?

Answer (score 0):

On your view controllers, you can manually set the "Back" text to whatever you like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil)
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target:nil action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
```

If the user changes the language, just run the code again to reset the back bar button item.

I recommend doing this in an abstract subclass, so you don't need to execute this code everywhere.

> What if I need the same for UIImagePicker text?

`UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, so:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = //make your image picker…
imagePicker.delegate = self;

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController *vc = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
    [vc.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
}
```

Comment: What if I need the same for UIImagePicker text?

Comment: @Dejel Updated with an example.  You basically just have to change the navigationItem's backBarButtonItem.

Comment: Thanks - but UIIMagePicker has text like Choose - how can I control this text?

Comment: Look up UINavigationItem - you can change its title.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html

Comment: Also, these follow-up questions are off-topic from your original question (they should be posted separately as different questions.)

Comment: The text in UIImagePicker - why is it related to UINavigationItem?